# Use existing module object in bundle files created by browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I have two files: `a.js` and `b.js`.

`a.js`:

```
console.log(require("./b.js")());
module.exports = function () {
   console.log("Hello Mars!");
};
```

`b.js`:

```
module.exports = function () {
    console.log("Hello World");
};
```

---

By bundling these files I obtain `c.js`:

```
browserify a.js -o c.js
```

I expect `c.js` to export a function (that prints `Hello Mars` when called). By `require`ing `c.js` in a node process I get an empty object.

```
$ node
> c = require("./c.js")
Hello World
undefined
{}
> c()
TypeError: c is not a function
    at repl:1:1
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:252:27)
    at bound (domain.js:287:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:300:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:417:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:210:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:549:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:826:14)
```

Since `node` has already a `module` object, how can I tell Browserify to use this `module` object for the main file, so I will get the `Hello Mars` function in the `module.exports` when using `require` in Node?

I checked out the docs, but I didn't find any option... Maybe I miss something.

I just want to bundle a module (that has dependencies) and `require` it in a node process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the following option:

> --standalone -s
>   Generate a UMD bundle for the supplied export name.
>                      This bundle works with other module systems and sets the name
>                      given as a window global if no module system is found.

You might also want to pass the `--node` option, to turn off the transformation of Node specific features.

Comment: [`--node`](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/1501#issuecomment-186766505) does something else, `--require` is expected to do this, but it doesn't work. And I also don't really want to create globals. Anyways, `-s` is the best one yet. Waiting for @substack feedback. :)

Comment: What makes you think globals would be created? He option says *"This bundle works with other module systems and sets the name given as a window global **if no module system is found.**"* Since Node does have a module system, it wouldn't create a global. As for `--node`: it includes `--bare`, which says: *"This is handy if you want to run bundles in node"*. It seems that's exactly what you want to do. `--require` doesn't have anything to do with node.

Comment: Right, in fact creating globals when there is no module system is not that bad, but still I search for an option that doesn't do that at all. I want to have export functionality in the bundle file but to not create any globals even when there is no module system. Anyways, accepting for now. :) Thanks a lot!